# VBA Code for getting the maximum and minimum value of the defined range from multiple Excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

The issue can be summarized as follows: I need to get the maximum and minimum value of the defined range from multiple workbooks in the same folder in the summary file. Let us say I have 100 XLSX files, I need to get 100 max and min values with the file name for this value.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If you have bunch of identical files in one folder, the easiest way to do this is by using Power Query. As an inspiration see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113603/power-query-combine-two-tables-from-1-file-and-repeat-procedure-for-all-files-w

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.